# Explaining why integral and summation can be swapped

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have the series $e^{-t^2}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k}}{k!}$ and I want to put it into the definition of $erf(z)$ to deduce the Maclaurin series for it.

However, I have 
$$erf(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ze^{-t^2}dt=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^z\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k}}{k!}dt$$
and I need to be able to swap the order of the integral and summation to get the required result $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kz^{2k+1}}{k!(2k+1)}dt$
.

How do I explain that it is possible to swap them? I know a theorem that states something along the lines of if $u_k(z)$ converges and there exists a series $\sum M_k$ that converges such that $|u_k(z)| \leq M_k$ for all $M_k$ then it is possible the swap the two. However, I am not sure if that is relevant here.

It is clear that $z \geq t$, so can $z$ simply be all the $M_k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uniform convergence is what allows you to make the swap. It is a fact that power series converge uniformly in compact subsets of their domain of convergence $D$, so for each $z$ you just need to think of it being in some compact subset $z \in K_z \subset D$. Since you can find such a $D_z$ for all $z$ in the domain of definition, it holds for all $z \in D$.

The theorem you are thinking of is the Weierstrass M test for uniform convergence.